# Bottom margin of div block not taking effect

Tags: html, css

I have a few nested `div` blocks and my problem is that the last one `left_navigation_container` doesn't have a 7px spacing at the bottom margin and I'm not sure why ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJ6Je/)).

HTML:

```
<div class="left_navigation_outer">
    <div class="left_navigation_header_outer">
        <div class="left_navigation_header_logo">
            <strong>Title</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left_navigation_container">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.left_navigation_outer {
    background: green;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px #ababab;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px #ababab;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px #ababab;
}


div.left_navigation_header_outer {
    background: blue;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 4px solid black;    
}

div.left_navigation_header_logo {
    line-height:50px;
    color: #efefef;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.left_navigation_container {
    background: red;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the way of calculating margin for this element - it refers to the its siblings', not parent's position.

You can set margin for other div containing "TITLE" text and see same issue with margin-top.

EDIT: You can add `<div style="width: 100%; height: 1px;"></div>` after `<div class="left_navigation_container"></div>` to trigger bottom margin and make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that by giving `div.left_navigation_outer` a `padding-bottom`

Comment: I thought of that, but when I apply the padding, the margin for `left_navigation_container` takes effect, so I've got twice the amount of space I actually want. I could just remove the bottom margin, but I kind of want to know why this is happening.

Comment: ahh - beat me to it with the `padding-bottom` idea

Comment: I can't explain exactly why it happens. But it happens from time to time and this has at every time solved it.

Comment: Do I get an explanation why the downvote? I see nothing wrong in my answer.

Comment: @sooper you can prevent the additional space by giving a `padding-bottom:0.1px;`

Comment: @SvenBieder Thanks I'm aware of that, see my comment for the other answer. I don't think this answer deserved a down-vote however, +1

Answer (score 1):

Weird... not sure why but if you add a padding-bottom `1px` to `div.left_navigation_outer` it fixes it - here's my [fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYLyE/)

```
div.left_navigation_outer {
    background: green;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px #ababab;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px #ababab;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px #ababab;
    padding-bottom:1px; /* tricky hack to get the bottom spacing */
}
```

Comment: I'd feel very uncomfortable adding a pixel to the bottom and letting it fix itself. I think it would be better to add a 5px padding to the bottom and remove the 5px margin from the `left_navigation_container`. But I still would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: I agree it is always good to know **why** something happens the way it does, so you're not programming-by-coincidence. To be honest I'm not sure, I just 'fiddled' until I got the bottom spacing!